# Extracting a key/value pair from an NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there a convenient way to obtain both a key/value pair from an NSDictionary?

Say I have a NSDictionary, partyGuest,

```
{
   name = "jim";
   age = 28;
   occupation = "astronaut";
   favouriteMeal = 
      {
         starter = "fish head soup";
         mainCourse = "roast armadillo";
         dessert = "sugar plum fairy cakes";
      }
}
```

I'd like to get obtain a key/value pair within that, like so,

```
NSDictionary *guestFoodChoice = [partyGuest itemForKey:@"favouriteMeal"];
```

...and have that obtain both the key and the value,

```
   guestFoodChoice =
{
   favouriteMeal = 
      {
         starter = "fish head soup";
         mainCourse = "roast armadillo";
         dessert = "sugar plum fairy cakes";
      }
}
```

It seems there should be, but as I can't see an obvious method, maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you basically want to get a dictionary with some subset (maybe just one) of key-value pairs in another dictionary. If that's right, the Key-Value Coding method `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:` is what you want.

```
NSDictionary *guestFoodChoice = [partyGuest dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"favouriteMeal"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

[See `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:`.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *guestFoodChoice = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[partyGuest itemForKey:@"favouriteMeal"],@"favouriteMeal",nil];
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, that (using valueForKey) is my current work-around, but I was thinking there should be a more elegant shortcut.

Comment: Create a category on NSDictionary where you add the code of the work-around, then at least you can clean up the code in your main project (make it more readable). I'd call the method something like `-keyedDictionaryWithObjectForKey:`